# C++ printf large buffer

Tags: c++, sockets

The problem I am having is printf doesnt print all the data that is being returned from a client response. (verified data is being sent back via packet sniffer)

```
#define MAXBUFFER    24576
char buffer[MAXBUFFER];
......
datastream = read(sock,buffer,MAXBUFFER - 1);
printf("%s",buffer);
......
```

What is the best approach to printing all the client data to the console ... while eliminating the potential of a BOF?

Comment: How do you want the data to look on the console?

Comment: How much data is sent, and how much is missing on stdout?

Comment: Mark - Exactly as the client sends it. eg (ps output)
Dan - The amount of data that is sent back is less than the MAXBUFFER

Comment: If this is C++, why use printf to begin with? If this is binary data, and you expect to see a human readable printout, you'll need to preprocess the data regardless of using C's printf or C++'s `std::cout` (in order to render printable non-printable characters). Addtionally, `read` returns the number of bytes read - stored in your `datastream` variable. You should not expect more bytes to be written (and arguably less - see below responses) than the number `datastream` contains. Additionally, if `datastream` is less than zero, you've an error.

Comment: Looking over a number of the answers given, and the various comments, I think that I still don't really know what your problem is. Perhaps printf() is behaving perfectly, but read() isn't accessing as much data as you think it should?

Answer (score 11):

Possible causes:

1. `read` is not guaranteed to read all the data at once it just attempts to do so, that's why it returns the number of chars read;
2. `printf` with `%s` will print until the first `'\0'` [ASCII code 0] in your buffer.

Comment: Thats the problem the output from the client contains a 0 how to I work around this?

Comment: Additionally, if your buffer does NOT contain any 0s, you'll CRASH

Comment: @ekronnenburg: It sounds like the data is in binary format (the bytes may include a mixture of printable and unprintable characters.) If that's the case, you need to convert them to a printable format before you can successfully print them to stdout.

Comment: The data is actually remote commands that is "ps aux" is sent from the (server) cmd -> (client) exec "ps aux" and returns the output back to the server (reverse connect). So null "0" kills the stream on the server console.

Comment: @ekronnenburg Not really sure how the output of `ps aux` can have `0` in the middle of it...

Comment: @Will: Actually, it's possible for you not to crash. You will invoke undefined behavior, which means it's perfectly legal for the compiler to format your hard drive.

Comment: @ekronnenburg you are not clear. You say that you are sending a command like "ps aux" which i believe should not require this huge buffer.

Comment: Example of a ps aux output from remote machine

root      4682  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul23   0:00 [kmpathd/3]
root      4683  0.0  0.0      0   <-(dies here)

Once I hit the enter key the rest follows

  0 ?        S<   Jul23   0:00 [kmpath_handlerd]
root      4711  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul23   0:19 [kjournald]
root      4713  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul23   0:00 [kjournald]

Comment: @ekronnenburg I think you're confusing the printable char `0` ASCII code 32 with the not-printable char `\0` ASCII code 0 (or I did not do a good job explaining it in the first place).

Also from your question & code it's not very clear how the 'hit enter key' part got involved in this...

Answer (score 11):

If the buffer has any zero bytes, they will be treated as string terminators.  Is this an ASCII or binary protocol?  If the latter, you might want to convert to hex before printing.

Comment: +1. This was the first thing I thought of. Should probably clarify the meaning "zero bytes" though.

Answer (score 2):

1) You may need to flush stdout to get the data to display: `fflush(stdout);`

2) If there's a **lot** of data, then you probably need to use a loop to read from the socket. (If you go this route, you can probably decrease the value of MAXBUFFER, not that you necessarily have to.)

Note: Production code must also recognize when the end of a discrete message has been received -- whether by using a length count, or looking for a specific termination code, or some other means. That's not shown here. (If you use a length count, it's easy enough to sum up the values of "bytesRead" to keep track.)

```
// Add a byte at the end to allow for a terminating null char
char buffer[MAXBUFFER + 1];
buffer[MAXBUFFER] = '\0';
    //... 
    int bytesRead;
    while((bytesRead = read(sock, buffer, MAXBUFFER)>0)) {
        printf("%s", buffer);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int numberofbytesread = read(sock,buffer,MAXBUFFER - 1);
write(1, buffer, numberofbytesread);
```

You should use [write(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) instead of printf, as you state you wish to send the data 'raw'. That's my understanding of your response to Dan.

Comment: I used write and its exhibiting the same behaviour as printf

Comment: OK then. I must admit I'm no longer sure what the problem is. Can you be more specific. How many characters are being read? i.e. What is the return value from read()? And how many characters are printed by printf() or write()? Both those functions return the number of characters written.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example to understand you requirement.
Ans: Use write() if you have data with 0 or '\0'

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ret=0,i;
    char buf[25470];

    for(i=0;i<25470; i++)
    {
        buf[i] = 'a';
    }

    buf[2500] = 0;

    ret = printf("%s ", buf);
    printf("\n \n Printed using 'printf' = %d \n \n", ret);

    ret = write(1,buf,sizeof(buf));
    printf("\n \n Printed using 'write' = %d \n \n", ret);

    return 0;
}
```

And you really need this big buffer to send a command like "ps aux" ?

Comment: Using 

write(1, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

It still breaks using write

Example of a "ps aux" output from remote machine 

root 4682 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< Jul23 0:00 [kmpathd/3] root 4683 0.0 0.0 0 <-(stream dies here)

Once I hit the enter key the rest follows 

0 ? S< Jul23 0:00 [kmpath_handlerd] root 4711 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< Jul23 0:19 [kjournald] root 4713 0.0 0.0 0 0 ? S< Jul23 0:00 [kjournald]